# Should consistency be considered as a concept in the metatheory?

Tags: lo.logic, metamathematics

Consider the statement: "ZFC is consistent". Normally this is considered at first sight as a statement in the metatheory. But if we follow Kunen's (informally) description of what the metatheory is (i.e., finitistic reasoning), there seem to be some problems to place that statement precisely at the metatheoretical level.

First of all, since ZFC is not finitely axiomatizable, it seems the metatheory fails to absorb the theory ZFC as a whole, and instead we should first develop some finitely axiomatizable fragment of set theory within which we can correctly formulate the theory ZFC.

But suppose we work with a finitely axiomatizable theory T. Does it make sense now to ask in the metatheory whether T is consistent? At first sight, the consistency of a theory as a concept supposes we can quantify over all possible formal proofs within the theory and assert that none of them actually ends in contradiction. But isn't this a set-theoretical analysis? Shouldn't we first develop some set theory and only then define set-theoretically the concept of consistency?

Of course if T happens to have a finite model, we are inclined to assert, in the metatheory, that we can never find a proof of a contradiction. But instead of saying that T is consistent, shouldn't we just say that T has a finite model? Or is the conclusion of consistency from this a valid finitistic reasoning that should be part of the metatheory?

Finally, what if T does not have a finite model? It seems to me that some intuitionistic approach should be taken in the metatheory, in the sense that concepts such as inconsistency are meaningless unless we can actually find a specific proof of a contradiction.

Comment: As long as the metatheory includes a small amount of arithmetic, you can just treat consistency statements about effectively axiomatized theories as the corresponding $\Pi^0_1$ sentences. If that's not what you're asking about, could you clarify the question some? 

Comment: In that case consistency just reduces to a statement within the theory. But is there any prior concept in the metatheory that expresses that notion? For example, if a certain theory T does not have the right amount of arithmetic needed to produce consistency statements, the only way I see to express the concept of consistency is to develop first some set theory S that includes infinite sets and work within S to interpret the axioms of T. Then consistency would actually appear at this theoretic level, expressed by some sentence in S, but we would be working with a copy of T inside S.

Comment: Could you expand by what you mean by "finitistic reasoning"? For example, in your view is there a finitistic proof that $\forall x \forall y(x + y = y + x)$ holds in the natural numbers? If not, then you will certainly have problems expressing the consistency of ZFC in your metatheory.

Comment: @ François: By finitistic reasoning I intend to mean only what involves quantification over finite sets and can be hence "verified" after a finite number of steps. Finite models are allowed, but there is no such concept as the natural numbers as a whole. Therefore, instances of commutativity law are ok but there is no proof of the sentence you mention. To state that sentence and its proof it would be necessary to develop some set theory that interprets finite sets "from the outside", since infinity is definitely excluded in this view.

Comment: (continued) But isn't this the standard way to view metatheory? I thought that any appeal to infinity would be consider some sort of cheating, as that concept should only exists formally, within some proper set theory (and being therefore a finitistic notion).

Comment: I beg to differ. In order to be able to treat universally quantified statements about natural numbers there is no need to develop any amount of set theory. It is sufficient to develop induction principles that tell us how to prove universally quantified statements about natural numbers. Such induction principles can be understood as descriptions of what natural numbers are, and they certainly need not presuppose that the totality of natural numbers has the same status as the number 42.

Comment: Let me clarify another point. Induction and recursion are rules which tell you how to do something. They do not presuppose any kind of infinity or anything like that. Which is why I essentially agree with Carl's first comment.

Comment: @ Andrej: I guess those notions of induction and recursion would certainly qualify as finitistics. I'm just wondering whether in the background one is not actually assuming that first order arithmetic is consistent (intuitively speaking), which I wouldn't want to do.

Comment: I like to think of myself as being consistent, even though I tend to believe in the axioms of Peano arithmetic.

Comment: Most people (including you, according to the comments) accept induction and primitive recursion as finitistic. It is no great trouble to formalize Con(T) as a statement of the form $\forall x P(x)$, where $P(x)$ is primitive recursive. As such, Con(T) is a perfectly meaningful statement. Whether it is true or not is up to you to decide, but it is meaningful nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, I think I tend to agree now with Carl's first comment. At first I thought he was appealing to first order arithmetic, but as long as induction and recursion are seen as finitistic methods/algorithms then we are still in the metatheory. Perhaps he or someone can expand that in an answer, also stressing the need to think of induction/recursion processes as finitistic to be able to characterize consistency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most people regard induction and recursion as finitistic. As Andrej Bauer commented:

> Induction and recursion are rules which tell you how to do something. They do not presuppose any kind of infinity or anything like that.

As a consequence, the standard weak metatheory used in practice is [Primitive Recursive Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic) (PRA).

Although very weak, PRA is strong enough to formalize [Gödel coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering). Using such coding, the axioms of ZFC (to take a concrete example) can be enumerated and recognized by primitive recursive functions. One can also recognize formal proofs from ZFC axioms using a primitive recursive function.

Thus, there is a primitive recursive function $B_{ZFC}(x,y)$ which takes value $0$ if and only if the numeral $x$ is a Gödel code for a formal proof of the Gödel coded sentence $y$ from the axioms of ZFC. Taking $y$ to be the Gödel code for your favorite contradiction, say $0 = 1$. The consistency of ZFC can be expressed as $\forall x (B_{ZFC}(x,y) \neq 0)$. As Carl Mummert pointed out, this is a simple $\Pi^0_1$ statement in PRA. While we don't know whether it is true or false, it is a perfectly meaningful statement from the finitistic point of view.